# Using logical equivalence to prove PL statements

Tags: logic, proof, theorem-proving

I'm trying to use those [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) as axioms to prove some [PL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) statements,
In this case I followed the examples in the documentation that didn't use the build-in logic functions$\{\text{And}[,],\text{Or}[,],\text{etc}\}$, the reason is, otherwise it will evaluate some axioms as True.

Here is my code: (Updated)

```
PL = {ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, True] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, False] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, True] == True],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, False] == False],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, p] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, p] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[not[p]] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, q] == or[q, p]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, q] == and[q, p]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[or[p, q], r] == or[p, or[q, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[and[p, q], r] == and[p, and[q, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, and[q, r]] == and[or[p, q], or[p, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, or[q, r]] == or[and[p, q], and[p, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[and[p, q]] == or[not[p], not[q]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[or[p, q]] == and[not[p], not[q]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, and[p, q]] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, or[p, q]] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, not[p]] == True],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, not[p]] == False]}
proof = FindEquationalProof[
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, 
   and[or[and[and[r, not[q]], not[p]], 
      and[q, not[and[q, not[or[p, r]]]]]], 
     not[and[p, not[and[q, not[r]]]]]] == 
    or[and[and[p, q], not[and[r, q]]], and[r, not[p]]]], PL]
proof["ProofGraph"]
proof["ProofNotebook"]
```

I just fixed the typo in the axiom, yet trying to let it prove that statement:

$$((r ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬p) ∨ (q ∧ ¬(q ∧ ¬(p ∨ r)))) ∧ ¬(p ∧ ¬(q ∧ ¬r))$$

$$\equiv(p ∧ q ∧ ¬(r ∧ q)) ∨ (r ∧ ¬p)$$

```
and[or[and[and[r, not[q]], not[p]], 
          and[q, not[and[q, not[or[p, r]]]]]], 
         not[and[p, not[and[q, not[r]]]]]] == 
        or[and[and[p, q], not[and[r, q]]], and[r, not[p]]]], PL]
```

But seems not work, i tried shorter ones, which works fine, is it because this  statement too long or something I missed $?$

However it can be proved with booleanLogic axioms  given in documentation, with 402 steps:

```
booleanLogic = {ForAll[{a, b}, and[a, b] == and[b, a]],
ForAll[{a, b}, or[a, b] == or[b, a]],
ForAll[{a, b}, and[a, or[b, not[b]]] == a],
ForAll[{a, b}, or[a, and[b, not[b]]] == a],
ForAll[{a, b, c}, and[a, or[b, c]] == or[and[a, b], and[a, c]]],
ForAll[{a, b, c}, or[a, and[b, c]] == and[or[a, b], or[a, c]]]}

proof = FindEquationalProof[
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, 
   and[or[and[and[r, not[q]], not[p]], 
      and[q, not[and[q, not[or[p, r]]]]]], 
     not[and[p, not[and[q, not[r]]]]]] == 
    or[and[and[p, q], not[and[r, q]]], and[r, not[p]]]], booleanLogic]
proof["ProofGraph"]
proof["ProofNotebook"]
```

And here is the proof graph:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could build a truth table (true and false) for each value of p, q and r. That might identify any invalid axioms.

Comment: the third-to-last axiom seems wrong: $\lnot(p\lor q)\equiv\lnot p\lor\lnot q$ should be $\lnot(p\lor q)\equiv\lnot p\land\lnot q$

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks!

Comment: I think True and False in your axioms make problems. Try to replace these by T and F. My comp is too weak to realize my suggestion (so does my Mathematica Online).

Comment: @user64494 My free online cloud can't run it too $\dots$ but I tried use it to prove two [Consensus theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem), where Identity, Domination, Negation laws play a important roles in the proof:
\begin{align}
&\text{1. or[or[and[x,y],and[not[x],z]],and[y,z]]==or[and[x,y],and[not[x],z]]]}\\
&\text{2. and[and[or[x,y],or[not[x],z]],or[y,z]]==and[or[x,y],or[not[x],z]]}\\
\end{align}
and both axiom works, use True, Flase seems make no difference from T,F, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The first four axioms are provably redundant; removing them creates a system that works.

```
PL2 = {ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, p] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, p] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[not[p]] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, q] == or[q, p]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, q] == and[q, p]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[or[p, q], r] == or[p, or[q, r]]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[and[p, q], r] == and[p, and[q, r]]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, and[q, r]] == and[or[p, q], or[p, r]]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, or[q, r]] == or[and[p, q], and[p, r]]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[and[p, q]] == or[not[p], not[q]]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[or[p, q]] == and[not[p], not[q]]],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, and[p, q]] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, or[p, q]] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, not[p]] == True],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, not[p]] == False]}
proof = FindEquationalProof[
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, 
   and[or[and[and[r, not[q]], not[p]], 
      and[q, not[and[q, not[or[p, r]]]]]], 
     not[and[p, not[and[q, not[r]]]]]] == 
    or[and[and[p, q], not[and[r, q]]], and[r, not[p]]]], PL2]
proof["ProofGraph"]
proof["ProofNotebook"]
```